# How do I change language (not dictionary!) in Excel 2011 for Mac?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, language

How do I change language in Excel 2011 for Mac?

**I'm not asking about the dictionary**, I'm asking about the language of the program itself, i.e. the one of the menus.

(in case this matters, I'm using the trial of Office 365)

Comment: Depending on how desperate you are to change your Office suite language, I suggest trying LibreOffice (www.libreoffice.org). It allows you to use whatever language you can, independent of the language of your Operating System. Unless you do very specific stuff like working with VBA, LO will serve you just fine.

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio with all due respect, I find the Libre suite to be… lacking, to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the localized version. It doesn't look like LIPs support OS X:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/office-language-interface-pack-lip-downloads-HA001113350.aspx

Comment: Mmh that's pretty incomplete, I was looking for English but it's not there...

Comment: @Lohoris, English is listed as a purchased language. BTW, have you noticed the difference between the freely available languages (Assamese, Konkani, Telugu...) and the paid ones (Arabic, English, French, Spanish...)? :P

Answer (score 1):

Office 365 uses the language of your location as a default selection, the one from the settings in the microsoft account that you use. I had the same issue, had to contact microsoft support to help me change it, this will help with both the language of the program and the language of the formulas that it uses.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-your-personal-language-and-region-settings-caa1fccc-bcdb-42f3-9e5b-45957647ffd7

You might have to install your trial once again, contact microsoft if issue persist, they do kind of help with their chat thingy